# how to do a dynamic number of objects in a cell inside a listview?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an app I'm working on, and I want to do cells inside a list view
but each cell has a different number of objects inside, 
best way to describe it is with a picture,

[image]

how could something like this be achieved?

Comment: you can achieve by using nested RecyclerView for that, https://android.jlelse.eu/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047

Comment: @Chandan Sharma  yea but i dont want the items (item 1, 2, 3, 4) to be like a scrollable, i want it to increase the size based on the items i'm adding and just to add them as static items

Comment: You can also do that simply use setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) in chid recyclerview.

Comment: Use [Groupie](https://github.com/lisawray/groupie) to easily manipulate the subgroups(sublist) in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing it with this code, I hope it helps:

```
for(int a = 0; a < items.size(); a++){
    ArrayList<String> current = items.get(a);
    Log.d("Current item", current.toString());
    RecyclerView myRecyclerView = new RecyclerView(this);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager myLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);

    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(); //Implement your custom Adapter
    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    myRecyclerView.setPadding(40,10,40,10);

    myRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View p_v, MotionEvent p_event)
                {
                    return true;
                }
        });

    GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
    border.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF); //white background
    border.setStroke(2, 0xFF000000); //black border with full opacity
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        myRecyclerView.setBackgroundDrawable(border);
    } 
    else {
             myRecyclerView.setBackground(border);
    }

    LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
    ll.addView(myRecyclerView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ((items.length*80) + 20)));
}
```